# Updating cell values in JTable in real time while typing

Tags: swing, jtable

I am using a JTable and I let the user fill it in with integers in one of the columns (the interface with the table pops out in a seperate window). When I type a value and press "ENTER" and then close the window everything saves fine. However, if I just type something in one of the cells and close the window, when I reopen it the new cell values are not there.

I would like the values to be updated in real time as I type every single character. Is it possible? I've tried applying a TableCellEditor, but I couldn't get it to work.

I've also tried add a KeyListener to the JTable, but the KeyPressed wouldn't invoke at all.

Comment: dont fully understand what exactly you'r trying to achieve (the input field is the editor inside the table itself? If so try to set the client property: table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.True) btw, never use KeyListeners

Comment: thanks kleopatra, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(making my comment an answer, so you can close it :-)

Assuming the input field is the editor inside the table itself, set the client property:

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.True)
```